# How to access the original module scope when `sys.modules` contains a different object?

Tags: python

How could I import `my_module` and modify the value of `_value` without modifying `my_module.py`? Is the original symbol table of `my_module.py` available somehow even though it's overwritten with `MyModule` instance in `sys.modules`?

```py
# my_module.py
import types, sys

_value = 5


class MyModule(types.ModuleType):
  @property
  def value(self):
    global _value
    return _value


sys.modules[__name__] = MyModule(__name__)
```

What I'm looking for is a technique to achieve this:

```py
import my_module

assert my_module.value == 5

# Some code to alter `_value`

assert my_module.value == 7
```

Comment: I'm looking to alter the original `_value` reference in the original scope, not to for example overwrite `sys.modules["my_module"].value` property with something that returns 7.

Comment: maybe `assert my_module.value==5`

Comment: Sorry about that, I never actually use `assert` ;p I'll edit the question, but the problem stands

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fill in your goal but let us try. It might help...

```py
#file my_module.py
class MyModule:

    _value = 5 #this is a class attribute

    def get_value(self):
        return MyModule._value #referred to prefixed by the class Name

    def set_value(self,val):
        MyModule._value = val 

    value = property(get_value, set_value) #clearer than the decorator, to me
```

In a shell :

```
>>>from my_module import *
>>>m = MyModule() #instantiate an object
>>>m.value #returns 5
>>>m.value = 7
>>>m.value #returns 7
```

Comment: The problem is constrained: I cannot modify the original `my_module.py`. 2 additional problems with the answer: The original example shows that `_value` is not a class attribute but a module level variable of `my_module.py`.  Also, the way that `MyModule` is loaded is constrained, you can only `import my_module`, I don't have a reference to the `MyModule` class (for the same reason that I don't have a ref to `_value`), and somehow, through some other means I'd like to modify the underlying `_value` of `my_module.py` which is not a part of the object that is returned from `import my_module`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following fits in, its the closest I can get, withoud all the dark sorcery...

```py
#my_module.py
_value = 5

class MyModule:

    def get_value():
        return _value 

    def set_value(val):
        global _value
        _value = val
```

in a shell

```
>>>from my_module import *
>>>MyModule.get_value()
5
>>>MyModule.set_value(7)
>>>MyModule.get_value()
7
```

Comment: Yea by adding a `set_value` in the original file I could solve it, but I can't :/ The Python interpreter still has access to the `_value` because it can read it in `def value` so I was wondering if it is accessible externally as well

Comment: Thanks for your attempts though ;)

Comment: somehow this is an undesirable behavior, it would somehow violate the data hiding principle, when you think of modules as semantical units.

Comment: Well there is no data hiding principle in Python. For example, you'll notice the lack of a `private` statement. It's one of Python's principles not to hide things in fact. What's going on here is that the only reference you have to a module is stored in `sys.modules` but the module in my example deliberately overwrites this reference (which is endorsed by Python) to add custom top level module behavior (such as properties) to modules.

Comment: An unfortunate effect of that is that I don't have any references to variables declared in the module file but not included in the module object. Maybe I can find it through the garbage collector, since it should be counting how many things point to `_value` ;p

Comment: I was totally aware of lack of privacy, things relying of the gentle convention of underscore prefix. I don't know of the dark sorcery about sys.modules overwriting things. I might have a look to it some day... We pythonistas definitely need a "Python, the good parts" à la Crockford

Comment: It's not dark sorcery, make a file (say `file.py`) with the following code and import it: `import sys; sys.modules[__name__] = 5`. If you then `import file; print(file)` it will be 5 instead of a module ;) You can use this to make modules with special behaviors :)